# Emacs picking the wrong browser

Tags: html, web-browser

I'm working under org-mode.

When I click on a [http://example.com] link, it opens a tab in Firefox as expected. The `.emacs` config is: `'(browse-url-browser-function (quote browse-url-firefox))`

However, for links in the form `file:///localdir/myfile.html` it depicts the message `running /usr/bin/sensible-browser` and starts Opera.

Why would emacs do that? Why does it not use Firefox or defaults to my system default browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in a sense `sensible-browser` *is* a system default browser:-)

I believe that you need to [use the `update-alternatives` system](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2212948) to set that system default.

As to why Org mode is using `sensible-browser` instead of the browse-URL functionality, I suspect it's because for file URLs it tries to be clever.

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/bin/sensible-browser` is a shell script. `/usr/bin/gnome-www-browser` has a high priority.

File `sensible-browser`:

```
if test -n "$DISPLAY"; then
    if test -n "$GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID"; then
        if test -x /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser; then
          ....
        elif test -x /usr/bin/x-www-browser; then
           ....
        elif test -x /usr/bin/gnome-terminal && test -x /usr/bin/www-browser; 
           ......
```

So you can use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```

or

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

to select the default browser that org mode uses.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of good reasons why it might not be useful to open a given `file:` URL in a web browser, so org has a distinct mechanism for handling them and deciding what to do with them.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org-file-apps` <kbd>RET</kbd>

But in practice, Bob Uhl's answer is probably what you want?  If Firefox is your preferred browser, then you should probably have it set as your system default, rather than customizing multiple independent Emacs settings to override the system default in the same way.  (Caveat: I don't know how `sensible-browser` makes its decision, so the situation might not be as simplistic as I've assumed.)